# How to show products attributes in loop?

Tags: plugins

I added custom attributes to my products, and I would like to show one of these on the product loop page(loop/price.php). The attribue name is: "garan".

```
$garanvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_garan');

foreach ( $garanvalues as $garanvalue ) {
    echo $garanvalue->name;
    var_dump($garanvalue);
}
```

I used the code above, but the var_dump output the following:

```
array(1) {   ["invalid_taxonomy"]=>   array(1) ..
```

I hope you know solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just checking the obvious, did you global $product?

Comment: Post the code that registers the CPT, please.

Answer (score 0):

If the taxonomy name is garan then use garan as parameter for get_the_terms function instead of pa_garan.

Comment: It didn't help. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Use $garanvalues = get_the_terms( $product->ID, 'pa_garan');

Comment: Please explain **why** that could solve the problem.

Comment: Not helps. If you read my first post, you can see I used same method.